# how can i add new component on stackblitz

Tags: nativescript, stackblitz

i am using nativescript on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nativescript-stackblitz-templates-xt87ec).

i want to use a [tabview](https://v7.docs.nativescript.org/ui/components/tab-view) acording to this doc, i just add a tab on html. but i am not sure because normaly on stackblitz i have to add dependency when i add a new component.

```
<TabView id="tabViewContainer">
  <TabViewItem title="First Tab">
    <StackLayout>
      <Label text="First Tab" textWrap="true" color="white"> </Label>
    </StackLayout>
  </TabViewItem>
  <TabViewItem title="Second Tab">
    <StackLayout>
      <Label text="Second Tab" textWrap="true" color="white"> </Label>
    </StackLayout>
  </TabViewItem>
</TabView>
```

why my tab view not working ?
how can i add a dependency on stackblitz with nativescript ?

when i try to imported on my ts file:

```
import { TabView, TabViewItem, SelectedIndexChangedEventData } from "tns-core-modules/ui/tab-view";
```

it not found, because it is not in my package/json

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the angular syntax if you want to use it with angular (https://v7.docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-components/tab-view). Alternatively, you can use the ui-material-tabs plugin, which is more feature complete: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nativescript-community/ui-material-tabs

Updated project:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/nativescript-stackblitz-templates-tueuyd?file=package.json,src%2Fapp%2Fitem%2Fitem-detail.component.html